# Terminated due to signal: BUS ERROR (10) выводит 50 на 50

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели

вот такой вот код. То работает то в ошибку падает. Примерно 50 на 50.
Если кто знает подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_int(int arg) { 
    printf("%d", arg); 
}    

int f(int *array, int size) { 
    for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size / 2; i++, j--)
        {
            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        print_int(array[i]);
    }
            
        
    
    
    
    return 0;
}

int g(int* array, int* limit) { 
    for (int i = 0, j = *limit - 1; i < *limit / 2; i++, j--)
        {
            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }
    for (int* current = array; current < limit; current++)
        print_int( *current );
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    f( array, 9 );
    g( array, array + 9);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А что вы хотите добиться функцией `g`? Вы в ней разыменовываете второй аргумент `j = *limit - 1; i < *limit / 2;` — а он у вас выходит за рамки вашего массива, вот и получается UB...

Кажется мне, что вы хотели что-то вроде

```
int g(int* array, int* limit)
{

    for (int i = 0, j = limit - array - 1; i < (limit - array) / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }
    for (int* current = array; current < limit; current++)
        print_int( *current );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я видать не совсем понимаю указатели. Можете обьяснить чем ptr = &a; от *ptr = a; отличается?

Comment: Первое: в переменную `ptr` заносится адрес переменной `a`. Т.е. в памяти, выделенной для `ptr`, находится значение, которое представляет собой адрес `a`. Второе: в память по адресу, находящемуся в переменной `ptr`, записывается значение из переменной `a`. Т.е. компьютер обращается к памяти, выделенной для переменной `ptr`,читает оттуда адрес блока памяти, в который кладет значение переменной `a`. Так понятно?

Comment: Хм, а что тогда означает *ptr = &a ?

Comment: Второй вопрос почему в функции g почему limit - array - 1 ? т.е. обычно же мы в цикле пишем (размер минус один) чтобы не выходить за рамки массива. limit это размер массива, значит должно быть limit минус один. А тут надо limit - array - 1 т.е. размер минус массив(не понятно) минус один. Что то я запутался. Ну и еще не понятно почему не надо * ведь когда указатель ссылается не на адрес, а на саму переменную мы ставим * или не так? Если не сложно поясните пожалуйста. Осваиваю Си я по немногу:)

Comment: Занести в место в памяти, адрес которого хранится в переменной `ptr`, значение адреса переменной `a`.

Comment: Потому что `limit` не размер массива, а указатель за последний его элемент. А начинается массив с адреса `array`. Грубо - как если бы массив начинался не с нулевого индекса, а с какого-то другого.

Answer (score 2):

Второй аргумент в `g( array, array + 9);` - это указатель на "последний" элемент массива, который нельзя трогать. А вы в функции используете его как индекс *(это совсем разные вещи)*.
Циклом вы пытаетесь пройти по массиву, но берёте значение , и используете его как индекс *(это совсем разные вещи)*.

```
//  * limit - 1 == limit [ 0 ] - 1
//  * limit / 2 == limit [ 0 ] / 2
//  * (array + 9) - 1 == array [ 9 ] - 1
//  * (array + 9) / 2 == array [ 9 ] / 2

 for (int i = 0, j = *limit - 1; i < *limit / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }
```

Убираем звёздочки `* limit`, работаем указателями `limit` в цикле. Меняем работу по индексу `[ j ]` на работу по указателю `* j`.

```
int g(int* array, int* limit) { 
    int * j = limit - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ( limit - array ) / 2; i++, j--)
        {
            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = * j ;
            * j = tmp;
        }
    for (int* current = array; current < limit; current++)
        print_int( *current );
    return 0;
}
```